# Remove prefix from figure caption in tufte-book document class

Tags: floats, captions, tufte

I want to get rid of prefixes in figure captions. I use MikTeX, XeLaTeX and `tufte-latex` style class. I've tried three variants:

```
\caption*{Foto}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}
```

but no one helped. Am I doing something wrong?
Here's MWE:

```
\documentclass[nofonts]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.75]{square.png}
    \caption{Foto}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `caption` does almost nothing with the `tufte-book` class, because it redefines captions in an incompatible way. Do you want to remove all of `Fig. 1:`?

Comment: @egreg, yes, I wanted to remove all prefixes. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to remove only "Fig." (in Russian "Рис."), then

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{\thefigure}
\makeatother
```

in the document preamble will print the caption as

> 1: Foto

If instead you want to get rid also of the number and the colon, a slightly more complicated patch is required: the whole `\@caption` command must be modified.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@caption}
  {\noindent\csname fnum@#1\endcsname: \ignorespaces}
  {}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

With this code you'll get only

> Foto

Here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass[nofonts]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Palatino}
\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfont}{Palatino}

%%% With this code no name and number will appear
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@caption}
  {\noindent\csname fnum@#1\endcsname: \ignorespaces}
  {}
  {}{}
\makeatother

%%% Remove the above code and uncomment the following
%%% three lines if you still want the number
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{\thefigure}
%\makeatother



\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.75]{square.png}
  \caption{Foto}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The package `caption` can't be used because `tufte-book` redefines the code for captions in an incompatible way.

---

In case you want no prefix and no number, but still want a list of figures (of course without the numbers), add also the following code before `\makeatother`:

```
\pretocmd{\@tufte@lof@line}
  {\begingroup\let\numberline\@gobble}
  {}{}
\apptocmd{\@tufte@lof@line}
  {\endgroup}
  {}{}
```

The captions in the list will be links to the actual figure.

Comment: This falls short in two respects: Removing the counter stepping (if you insert a mix of numbered/unnumbered figures) and printing a LoF. Of course, since the OP wants "all prefixes" removed, this is sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

The following example goes one step further, also removing the details from the LoF, since `\@caption` includes this by default:

[image]

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{nocapfigure}
  {\let\H@refstepcounter\@gobble%
   \long\def\@caption##1[##2]##3{%
   \par%
   %\addcontentsline{\csname ext@##1\endcsname}{##1}%
   %  {\protect\numberline{\csname the##1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces ##2}}%
   \begingroup%
     \@parboxrestore%
     \if@minipage%
       \@setminipage%
     \fi%
     \@tufte@caption@font\@tufte@caption@justification%
     \noindent\ignorespaces##3\par%\noindent\csname fnum@#1\endcsname: \ignorespaces#3\par%
     %\@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
   \endgroup}\figure
    }{\endfigure}
\makeatother

\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.75]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Foto}
\end{figure}
\begin{nocapfigure}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.75]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Foto}
\end{nocapfigure}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.75]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Foto}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Removing the `\addcontentsline` part of `\@caption` removes the insertion of *everything* from the LoF. If you're interested in keeping the figure title, only part of `\addcontentsline` could be removed, as in:

```
\addcontentsline{\csname ext@##1\endcsname}{##1}%
  {\protect\numberline{}{\ignorespaces ##2}}%
```

Technically, this just drops the contents of `\numberline`, which provides the appropriate horizontal placement of the entry in the LoF.

The length of code via a patch (using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox), say) would be comparable to a redefinition of `\@caption` altogether, as I did in my example.